# Способствует ли ведение дневника грамотности?

Tags: другое

Сегодня подумал начать вести дневник и тут же приобрёл. Если Вы когда-то вели его, то он помогал Вам закреплять Ваши языковые знания? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Безусловно, любое письмо способствует закреплению навыков правописания. А если в затруднительных случаях Вы станете обращаться к словарям и справочникам,    эффект  только усилится.  Желаю терпения и прилежания.